# Can the norm be expressed as a polynomial with integer coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, diophantine-equations

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a cyclic extension of degree $n$ with basis $(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$. Any $b\in K$ can be expressed by

$$b=x_1v_1+\dots+x_nv_n,$$
where $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Do we know that

$$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b)\in\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots , x_n]?$$

Does it hold when $$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b)=1?$$

Comment: It will have integral coefficients in $x_i$ if the $v_i$ are algebraic integers.  For instance, with $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ we have $N(x+y \frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2})= x^2 + x y - y^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't hold.
Look at $\mathbb{Q} (i)$ with the basis $v_1=\frac{1}{2}+i$, $v_2=\frac{1}{3}+i$.
For it, we have:
$$w=x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2 = (\frac{x_1}{2} + \frac{x_2}{3} ) + (x_1+x_2)i ,$$
$$N(w)=(\frac{x_1}{2} + \frac{x_2}{3} )^2+(x_1+x_2)^2 \not \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2] .$$

Comment: You are right! Thank you! Do you know if it still doesn't hold, when $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b)=1$?

Comment: Do you mean $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ restricted to units? Then it is just 1,  clearly it is a polynomial with integer coefficients.